# ItemizedOverlay callback ondraw

Tags: android, android-mapview

i want to draw a pic and background  at the mapview,because only pic is ugly,so i want to give the pic a background. 
i want to use:

```
 public class MyItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {
{
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
{

       // super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);
       canvas.drawbitmap(pic,,,);
       canvas.drawbitmap(bg,)

}

....
```

}

but i cannot found invalidate() methods, how to finished the effect?

Comment: Have you tried [this?](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons/)